# DMP File Compression - Oracle EXPDP

Tags: oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g. Here i am Exporting the database using EXPDP. My database dmp file will be around 50 GB. So i am running out of space in Production Server. So i had tried COMPRESSION = "ALL" in ,my EXPDP command. While running this, i am getting something like "Not Enabled".

Here is EXPDP command.

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do set fdate=%%c%%a%%b
EXPDP username/password@sid COMPRESSION=ALL DIRECTORY=EXPDP_CUSTOM_DIR TABLESPACES=USER DUMPFILE = user.dmp
```

Whether i need to change anything in this..

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Invalid Operation - Feature not enabled.Dump File Data Compression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have licensed the Advanced Compression Option to use this feature. Options for export compression are pretty slim with data pump, otherwise. With the older export you could pipe the output through a compression program, but I don't think that's possible here.

You might consider specifying a maximum file size (1GB, say) and include a substitution variable in the dumpfile name so you produce a bunch of smaller files, and have a cron job watching for them and compressing them as soon as they export process releases them.